# Problems with pinvoke signatures throwing System.AccessViolationException with libuiohook

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to write a wrapper for [libuiohook](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook) in C# using P/Invoke.
But I can't even get the simple `hook_run` signature to work.

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Start();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Stop();
}

[DllImport("libuiohook", EntryPoint = "hook_stop", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] //StdCall gives the same problems
private static extern int Stop();

[DllImport("libuiohook", EntryPoint = "hook_run", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Start();
```

The native interface is: ([Full public interface](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook/blob/master/include/uiohook.h))

```
// Insert the event hook.
UIOHOOK_API int hook_run();

// Withdraw the event hook.
UIOHOOK_API int hook_stop();
```

It keeps throwing `System.AccessViolationException` or blocks at `Start()`.
What is the problem with the signatures?

Comment: Are you using the correct calling convention?

Comment: @Chris UIOHOOK_API is __declspec. But the I get the same problems using `CallingConvention.Cdecl`

Comment: The calling convention determines how arguments are passed.  They have none.  So that's not it.  There isn't any way to declare these functions wrong.  You'll need to debug the native code to discover the reason for the AVE.  You have the source so no problem.

Comment: @HansPassant There was indeed a problem with the lib. I found pre compiled files in the JnativeHook jar. Which worked. The blocking was caused because there wasn't a callback registered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was probably in the way I compiled the library.
Using pre compiled files only worked when a callback had been registered before calling `hook_run()`.

Comment: I suggest you delete the question because it can have no value to future readers.